# Vimeo mp4 video url PRO user JSONP request

Tags: jsonp, vimeo-api

I need to get direct mp4 url from vimeo videos.
I am a PRO, how can I access files uploaded by other users?

I try to do requests like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/<video id>/config',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

but it returns `: Unexpected token`

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you provided is not supported by Vimeo, and can (and will) break without any notice. The only proper way to do this is through the Vimeo API: https://developer.vimeo.com/api. Your video files will appear in the JSON representation of any video you own. The easiest way to find these videos is with the following api call

`GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos`